# how to access to wordpress dashboard?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services

[image]
[image]
hey there i hosted my site on AWS and it was all okay when i used ssl insecure content but unfortunately  i deactivated that plugin by mistake and it made me logout of my admin panel.

So, now when i try to access my dashboard by typing correct username it is not allowing me to sign in into it. please help me in  this. The first image shows how my login page looks (different from each time) and a popup box that appears when i try to login in my account and after clicking on it it reverts me back to same login page. please do help me i am depressed now.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, better to attach the valid SSL certificate as it's not only about your dashboard but the end-user will also face the same issue when they try to  access your website.

Or if you think that you were able to access your website with that plugin, then do the following

- Ssh to your instance
- install the plugin from the command line that you have removed and it will start working back.

```
wp plugin install <plugin-name>
```

[how-to-install-wordpress-plugins-wp-cli](https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/how-to-install-wordpress-plugins/)

Answer (score 0):

This is because your wordpress site is attempting to load your assets over HTTP rather than HTTPS.

Your SSL comes back as valid when running [SSL labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=webshivam.com) so there is no need to worry about your SSL being invalid.

This will come down to your site actually loading on HTTP behind the load balancer so it is not aware it should be loaded over HTTPS.

There is a small change you can make that fools your blog into believing that it should return HTTPS urls. At the top of your `index.php` file add the following

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 443;
```

By doing this only HTTPS urls will be rendered on your site allowing it to be fully accessible as intended.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of SSL Issue. Do the Following

1. Install Really Simple SSL Plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/
2. Change Site Url and Home URL Prefix from http:// to https://

Note:- Disable SSL and Install Plugin First in order to be Succesfully run it